# Importing a class into Eclipse IDE problem

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I've got a strange problem while working with Eclipse IDE.

I've added maven dependencies to pom file properly. My IDE recognizes new packages and classes but is not able to add them as I need them.

here is a screenshot from my working session:

[image]

As you can see, it knows that the class which I need is in `org.apache.sshd.server` package but clicking on `import ExitCallback` is useless and nothing happens after that.

I've never had such a problem like that before changing my OS.

Is it a not compatibility matter?
I'm working on a spring project with java 11 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `import` statements help tell the compiler what the *fully qualified* name of types are, so you'd import the fully qualified name of ExitCallback, meaning with the package name, not "ExitCallback".

Comment: Of course, I'm able to add it manually with full qualified name or even by pressing the short key `Ctrl + Space`. but not by clicking on it by mouse. this is a problem with whole code. mouse options are not working even in `declare local variable foo` option.

Comment: Isn't that what the first quick fix option is offering in your image? Are you saying that `declare local variable foo` is valid syntax?

Comment: Yes, but clicking on it is useless and nothing happens next.

Comment: That sounds like a bug that needs to be reported, then.

Comment: `declare local variable foo` is an option that IDE gives to you when you're using a variable which is not declared. I wanted to say that it is not working, too. (by clicking on this option).

Comment: Look at all your imports, there may already be an import for it that is failing.

Comment: removing all of imports, cause this problem for other classes, too.